# The centralizer $Z_G(X)$ of a nilpotent element in a real simple Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups

I am looking for the description of the centralizer  $Z_G(X)$ , where $G$ is a real simple Lie Group and $X\in \ Lie (G) $ such that $X^d=0,\ X^{d-1}\neq 0 $. It is is helpful to me any references or any suggestion .

There is a unpublished  manuscript by  R. Proud, on the title “On centralizers of unipotent elements in algebraic groups”.
If some one have a copy of this please post it.

Comment: It would probably be simplest to contact Ross Lawther and/or Donna Testerman, though Richard Proud did not remain active in mathematical research.   (By the way, a UCLA thesis by John Kurtzke in the late 1970s led to a couple of published papers on this theme, but only involving good prime characteristics.  My recollection is that there were flaws in his work.)

Comment: The first version of your question was very narrow, but this one is much too broad.   First, you need to clarify what a "nilpotent" element is in the Lie algebra of a real Lie group.  Beyond this, the description of centralzers (in the adjoint group) requires much case-by-case study using linear algebra, etc.  This depends on classification of (non-compact) real forms of complex Lie algebras and their classes of nilpotents.